# How to detect inline Firefox extension installation, and intercept it - Firefox extension development

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I am building Firefox addon am trying to detect inline installation of the Firefox extensions. To be clear, installations on the places that are not on the `Mozilla` domain. So, when I am on some website, and when I trigger the extension installation (the `.xpi` file), I want to redirect the user to some website.

Before that dialog box appears, and if that is not possible, very soon after that, the one for 'installation confirmation', I want to redirect the user.

I am not very familiar with the `download` API, and I really don't know where to start. I have tried adding the listener for the downloads, but no result from it.

**background.js** (and included `downloads` in `manifest.json`)

```
function handleCreated(item) {
  console.log(item);
}

browser.downloads.onCreated.addListener(handleCreated);
```

My expectations are to make my addon to recognize that the user is downloading a `.xpi` file, and perform redirection on some page when that happens.

Edit: 
Of the redirection is not possible, then replacing websites `.xpi` with another one would do the job also.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the list of what I have tried.

I have tried to convert the page into the text format using `.text()` fro `jQuery`, and then search for the URL that has `.xpi` at the end. However, this did not work for some cases. Sometimes, some websites are pulling the `.xpi` from their own server, using their own API. So it is not a golden solution to my problem.